# Show Functions and Procedures for a specific database only in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, stored-functions

Whenever I do `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS` or `SHOW FUNCTION STATUS`, the engine shows me the procedures and functions in ALL my databases and not the one I'm currently connected to.

Is there a way to list and/or retrieve information about procedures and functions from ONE specific database only? For example, if I'm in database "People", I want the query to only show me functions and procedures that exist in that database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these as in a more specific way

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db = 'databasename';
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'databasename';
```

Comment: Oh my god I feel so dumb right now... I literally can't believe I missed the 'Db' column. Should've drunk my coffee before asking on here. I oughta stay away from the pc when I'm sleepy.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT routine_name,ROUTINE_SCHEMA 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines 
WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA LIKE 'mydb';
```

You can find more information from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/routines-table.html).

Answer (score 1):

If your user has access to `mysql` schema, which is the engine/system.. you can try this:

```
-- display function/procedure details
SELECT db, name, type, 
    security_type, definer, 
    created, modified
FROM mysql.proc
-- filter out system function/procedure
WHERE db != 'sys'
    AND db = 'your_chosen_database'
ORDER BY type, db;
```